# Prove that $a_{n+1} = 2a_n+(-1)^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

> Let $a_0 = 0,a_1 = 1,$ and $a_n = a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$ for $n \geq 2$. Prove that $a_{n+1} = 2a_n+(-1)^n$.

We have $a_{n+1} = a_n+2a_{n-1}$ and we want to show this equals $2a_n+(-1)^n$. Do we prove this by induction or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

From $a_n = a_{n-1}+ 2a_{n-2}$ we get $$a_n -2a_{n-1} = -(a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}),$$ then the conclusion follow easily(call it induction or whatever). For example, let $b_n = a_{n+1} -2a_n$, we have $$b_n = -b_{n-1}=...=(-1)^n b_0 = (-1)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is any easier, but using induction explicitly can be avoided.

Let $ n \ge 1 $. Add $a_n$ to both sides to get $b_n = 2 b_{n-1} $ where $b_n := a_n+a_{n+1} \forall n \ge 1 $. This yields $ b_n = 2^{n-1} b_1 = 2^{n-1} $.

Thus 
\begin{eqnarray*} a_{n+1} &=& 2^n - a_n \\ &=& 2^n - 2^{n-1} + a_{n-1} \\ &=& \dots \\ &=& \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{n-j} 2^j + (-1)^n a_1 \\ &=& \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{n-j} 2^j + (-1)^n \\ &=& \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^{n-j} 2^j \mbox{.} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Factoring out 2 from the summation term in the second-last expression yields the desired equality.

Answer (score 0):

Previous *Answers* have shown how to prove an equation for a sequence $a_n$,which addresses the **first** part of your *Question*. This *Answer* focuses on the **second** part of your *Question*, namely:

*"Do we prove this by induction or is there an easier way?"*

Your question requires us to prove an equation:  $$a_{n+1}=2a_n+(−1)^n$$ that holds, implicitly, for *all* non-negative integers $n$.  Since there is a countable infinity of such integers, the abstract equation involving $n$ stands for a corresponding infinity of specific equations:
$$a_1=2a_0+(−1)^0$$
$$a_2=2a_1+(−1)^1$$
$$a_3=2a_2+(−1)^2$$
$$...$$

It is not practical to prove each and every one of those specific equations; nor even possible to do so in a finite amount of time.  Therefore, this is a perfect example of a case when we *need* the **Principle of Mathematical Induction**.  Although most mathematicians believe that induction is a reasonable proof procedure, there have been historically quite a few who do not admit the principle.  Consequently, their mathematical theories are considerably weaker than those that do use induction.

The first *Answer*, given by **S. Y**, mentions induction.  The second *Answer* attempts to prove your equation without using induction *explicitly*; however, the proof given there still relies on induction *implicitly*.

So the short answer to your question "is there an easier way" is: **Probably not**.  The only cases when we can prove an equation true for all [non-negative] integers, without using induction, are those which involve certain "simple" transformations of some similar equation that we know to be true.  For example, the sequence defined in your question is this:  $$a_n=a_{n−1}+2a_{n−2}$$  which is *defined* to be true for all $n≥2$.  The first *Answer* shows how we can transform that definition, and a similar one for $b_n$, into the equation  $$b_{n−1}=−b_{n−2}$$ using only basic algebra: simple arithmetic operations such as subtraction of like terms, and multiplication by a constant.  Those steps don't need induction.  However, the proof that  $$b_n=(−1)^n$$  for all $n≥2$ *does* need induction (as do most equations involving the $n^{th}$ power.)  So unless you can find some simple transformations of your given equation into the target equation - that is, the result you want, you're going to need induction.